# Conditional css in knockout databind

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am working in MVC3 with knockout in a simple table.

I want to apply some alternate row styling so I did

```
   <tr data-bind="css: { altrow: $index()%2 }">
```

This worked great.

Next I wanted to apply a special row styling for special rows. So I did

```
  <tr data-bind="css: { altrow: $index()%2 } ,css: { specialrow: IsSpecial == true }">
```

This worked OK. It appears to be stripping the CSS off of every line and then applying if the row is special. So it eliminates the alternate shading.

I would just like this to override any existing CSS if it exists.

Anyway I am a little stuck, and new to all of this. And my searches have turned up confusing results.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is not clear from your question that you have to have the `altrow` and `specialrow` class together when both condition true. Or you want `specialrow` when it's true but for the other cases `altrow` should be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two bindings with the same name for the same element. Knockout will only use the second one.  The `css` binding allows you specify more than one class though.

```
<tr data-bind="css: { altrow: $index()%2, specialrow: IsSpecial == true }">
```